# Spring security Issue: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat7

I have quite a problem with spring security.

Situation:

WEB.XML:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
```

security-config.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

ERROR:

> SEVERE: **Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined**   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:279)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:323)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Depedencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Show me your pom.xml.

Comment: Your  tag <listener- class> ? is this just a typo here ?

Comment: @AmitParashar  double checked and `<listener- class>` is not a typo. It might looks like it is but on my web.xml it is the right format

Comment: <listener- class> there is a space before class remove it <listener-class>

Comment: @SarfarazKhan This was a typo in my question, my web.xml file was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have these libraries:

spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar

spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar

But Maybe you application context is not loading your security context

classpath:spring/conf/security-context.xml

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Ok - the class org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy is pulled in with the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Give this a try.

Comment: Go to your eclipse package explorer view and verify that spring-web-xxxx.jar is under Maven Dependencies.

Comment: Yes. Just verified, no issue with the dependency.

Comment: In your log - even if you are at INFO level - you should have some messages related to spring release level and bean creation. Let's see that part of the log.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while configuring one of the project.The reason that I was getting this was I didn't mentioned my application context /root context xml file in the context param. I exactly don't remember exact explanation for this as it was 1 yr ago but doing this solved my issue.You can try putting you application context (root spring xml file) in context - param

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/config/security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Check out [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/79687-no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined?p=499250#post499250)